# Paypal userinfo only returns user_id

Tags: vb.net, paypal, userinfo

I am working with vb.net web application.
I want to get papyal user info by paypal credential.
My code below:

```
Dim url As String = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/userinfo?schema=openid"
            Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
            req.ContentType = "application/json"
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization", accesstoken)
            req.Method = "GET"
            Dim responseData As String = ""
            Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
                responseData = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
```

Response returns only User_id.

```
user_id: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/.............
```

But want to get all information of user.
How it possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PayPal API, but the documentation says you have to configure scopes for your app. Did you do that? `The attributes returned depend on the scopes configured for the REST ap`

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to configure scopes ? please suggest me.

Comment: Sorry, I already said I'm not familiar with PayPal API. But I'm sure the information is in the developer documentation.

Comment: How did you resolve it??